# BTC invalid transaction: double spending attempt?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, hash

I'm writing because I need some help in understanding the below hash data. Thank you.
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/976e6d64a4c98cf15ac917b98a04333f896b7cd15c1f2fdfb18f6fee668b670c

1. Is it a double spending attempt?
2. What is the recipient address valid transaction was sent to (how to retrieve it from hash data)?
3. The real amount B received from A in the valid transaction (not considering the utxo - unspent transaction output).

Thank you :)

Comment: I think it was RBF enabled transaction which got replaced with another transaction.

Comment: Its sender 12zVe8P1gzcJvHqMEozpzxVa2uqVPYtxVV is a weird bot.